# How to solve this weird multiple loops scenario (Java or C#)?

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, for-loop, binary

I've got this - possibly trivial - loop/combinations problem similar to binary combinations. I don't know how to approach it efficiently. Consider this scenario, I need unique loop to pass through all these combinations in a sequence:

```
Round  ABC

01.    000 <- values of A=0, B=0, C=0
02.    001
03.    010
04.    011
05.    100
06.    101
07.    110
08.    111

09.    002
10.    012
11.    102
12.    112
13.    020
14.    021
15.    120
16.    121 <- values of A=1, B=2, C=1
17.    022
18.    122
19.    220
20.    221
21.    222
```

Except there are 12 letters (A-L), and also the "bit" size is not just 0,1 or 2 but any integer number (from 0 possibly up-to 1000 or 1024, not to make it crazy). I know it's a huge load of combinations, but I'll just scrap just top few that also fulfill my other conditions. So no need to worry about computational madness.

Disclaimer: The order has to be exactly as shown above. NOT a multiple FOR loops going first 0-1024 for C, then B.

Thanks in advance, I just can't seem to find the way to "algorithm it".

Update: Added whole sequence for combinations of ABC/012

regards,
Kate

Explanation:

I've encountered this problem when trying to tackle  problem of analyzing sum of money for its combination of coins/notes:

For example $5001 to find out x optimal combinations.

```
10x $500 + 1x $1
50x $100 + 1x $1
..
```

Now letters (A,B,C..) correspond to a number of possible values of banknotes or coins ($1, $5,.. $100). While base correspond to a number of pieces of that banknotes/coins (for example $5001/$5000 = 1piece max.)

Comment: Interesting sequence - why does the second set (values 9 through 16) never have a "2" in the first position?

Comment: It does, it continues: 022, 122, 220, 221, 222,..

Comment: You'll probably want to explain the sequence, I find it unlikely that anyone would be able to determine the exact sequence with what you've given so far.

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion, I thought it was self-evident it continues in a "binary" fashion. I've edited it to contain full sequence for ABC/0-2.

Comment: In other words, you want count numbers in a base-12 numeric system. Do you have any idea how you would do it for base-2, base-10 or base-16 systems?

Comment: @Groo if it was that, the sequence would be 000, 001, 002, 003, ...

Comment: No, base is 0-1000 (dynamic). It can be A=999, B=123, C=56. The number of letters ("bits") is 12.

Comment: I guess as soon as you are able to express what kind of sequence you need in plain English, you will also have the algorithm you are looking for.+

Comment: @KitFisto: Oh crap, I though OP said "The order does **not** have to be exactly as shown above". Completely the opposite.

Comment: It's a challenge of its own to even understand exact rules for sequence progression. Almost like an IQ test.

Comment: I don't know if this problem/sequence got any name. I would probably found the solution on Google already. If anyone knows even how this problem is called. Feel free to tell me.

Comment: Groo: Yep, I'm puzzled too. I've spent 5 minutes just generating that sequence. When I think about the full solution, my mind go to sleep mode.

Comment: Where did you get this problem actually? What mandates this specific sequence order?

Comment: Hm, I still have no clue how the first sequence is supposed to help you in solving your problem. Do "letters" in your first example map to coins/notes? Shouldn't this mapping be strictly defined somewhere if the sum has to be constant? And if that is so, checking all possible combinations doesn't make sense. 2. What's the reason for the specified order? It is still unclear where you came up with that.

Comment: Sum is not a constant, it's entered by an user. He enters it, and a list of possible combinations is listed. The state space is really huge 125 billion combinations for 5001,- (for example) with 12 types of coins/notes (CZK). So the idea was to scan it in a most efficient way. First try the high value bills, and also the less of pieces of coins/notes the better.

Comment: if you had digits up to 3, would your sequence go 003,013,023,103,113,123,203,..?

Comment: @SmartK8: this **completely** changes the problem. First of all, this problem shouldn't be solved this way. It's a plain Knapsack problem. Why would you possibly want to check all combinations, if 99% of them don't add up to 5001 at all? And your sequence order is obviously wrong: how can 020 possibly sit between 112 and 120?

Comment: Groo: I'm not checking all the combinations, only the first 10 to give that sum. Can you shed some light on a knapsack problem, and its relevance to this problem? In other words, how to use it?

Comment: Hachi: I guess, it would go 003, 013, 103, 113, 023, 123, 203, 213, 223, 030, 031, 130, 131,.. :)

Comment: @SmartK8: google for "coin change algorithm": A [dynamic programming](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/jaa/CSG713.04F/Information/Handouts/dyn_prog.pdf) solution. Another [DP](http://blog.ivandemarino.me/2010/01/17/money-change-problem-greedy-vs-dyn-pro/) solution. Yet another [DP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31002/Coin-Change-Problem-Using-Dynamic-Programming) solution. [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). But I still have no clue how you imagined the ordering of that sequence.

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to solve coin change algorithm. We've solved it eventually, but I've encountered this problem, and it haunts me. The sequence is increasing in a binary fashion. When 2 is introduced it behaves like 1, and 0 and 1, behaves like a 2-bit number. When all combinations of 2-bits are depleted, change 2 like it is a bit, and so on. This ensures optimum of all three 1) high valued bills are tried first, 2) that small coin/bills counts are tried first, and 3) also that the combinations are unique.

Comment: *"change 2 like it is a bit"*: can you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: Well, when 2 is introduced in 002, then all binary combinations of 1 are realized in those two 00 (ending with case 112). Then a higher hierarchy of things moves the 2 in a binary fashion from 002 -> 020. Then all combinations of 1 are realized within 0x0 two free 0 positions (0x0, 0x1, 1x0, 1x1). Then again 2 is moved from 020 -> two "binary" like combination 022. So there are multiple layers. I'm now maybe realizing the hierarchy.

Comment: It's some recursive binary combinations hellish solution, but my mind can't quite reach it.

Comment: I think it can be formulated a bit clearer now. Rounds 1 to 8 are basically running 3 FOR cycles from 0 to 1. Then from round 9 it's the same thing: 3 FOR cycles but this time for 0 to 2, but somehow skipping combinations from 0 to 1 pass. So those are kinda "slices".

Comment: You are concentrating on describing the sequence rule too much, and I am trying to explain that there is nothing optimal about this sequence. What does "high valued bills are tried first" mean? Why isn't 000 followed by 100 then? Next, how can 020 be between 112 and 120? You go from 112 (four coins, high valued first), over 020 (two coins, middle valued first), to 120 (three coins, high valued first). How did you "weigh" that three coins in 120 should be considered after four coins in 112?

Comment: High valued is C in this case. As in A=$1, B=$2, C=$5 for example.

Comment: So basically if you're searching for $6. The result is in round 6. For $5 it is round 1.

Comment: Shouldn't 022 be before 121? You will say it doesn't comply with your binary twiddling. But they both have 4 coins, and "high values are tried first" in 022.

Comment: As I said, I'm not saying this is optimal structure for the coin-change. I just thought of it when we're solving it, and it haunts me, that I'm not able to devise an algorithm to build this sequence. Even though (at least in my mind it has fixed rules). I'm able to devise crazy complicated stuff (genetic, neural networks, 3D path-finding, CSG,..) but I'm not able to find this damned algorithm? As I said, it haunts me. :E

Comment: You're right it should have, if it was an optimal coin/bill count. But I would not be able to grip on anything with that structure. At least with this one it follows binary rules kinda. But if you are able to construct this, or your modified sequence, you can do any of those two. I'm talking about: 000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110, 111

Comment: I'm not even able to imagine a sequence for 2's. Is it 002, 012, 102,.. or 002, 020, 200,.. ? Damn, not enough brain capacity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I guess your sequence right, you will have it easier to generate it recursively

here an approach in Java, which should generate a sequence that matches your scenario.
I hope it helps you (maybe I add more explanation later):

```
public static void init() {
    // define constants
    final int length = 3;
    final char maxValue = '3';

    // define buffer
    final char[] array = new char[length]; java.util.Arrays.fill(array, '0');
    final boolean[] alreadySet = new boolean[length]; java.util.Arrays.fill(alreadySet, false);

    // fill first digit, then let the recursion take place
    for(char c = '1'; c <= (char)(maxValue); c++) {
        // iterate from lowest to highest digit
        for(int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // set value
            array[i] = c;
            alreadySet[i] = true;
            // print value
            System.out.println(new String(array));
            // call recursion
            recursive(array, c, i, alreadySet, length);
            // unset value
            alreadySet[i] = false;
            array[i] = '0';
        }
    }
}

public static void recursive(char[] array, char lastValue, int lastIndex, boolean[] alreadySet, int leftToSet) {
    // if we didn't set all digits
    if(leftToSet > 0) {
        // iterate from lowest to highest digit
        for(int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // missing all digits already set
            if(!alreadySet[i]) {
                // count from 1 to lastValue-1
                for(char c = '1'; c < lastValue; c++) {
                    // set value
                    array[i] = c;
                    alreadySet[i] = true;
                    // print value
                    System.out.println(new String(array));
                    // call recursion
                    recursive(array, c, i, alreadySet, leftToSet-1);
                    // unset value
                    alreadySet[i] = false;
                    array[i] = '0';
                }
            }
        }

        char c = lastValue;
        // iterate from lowest to highest digit
        for(int i = array.length-1; i > lastIndex; i--) {
            // missing all digits already set
            if(!alreadySet[i]) {
                // set value
                array[i] = c;
                alreadySet[i] = true;
                // print value
                System.out.println(new String(array));
                // call recursion
                recursive(array, c, i, alreadySet, leftToSet-1);
                // unset value
                alreadySet[i] = false;
                array[i] = '0';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement it, but I have troubles with "missing all digits already set"? What it means exactly?

Comment: if you set the 3 in 0030, then you iterate from 003* to 0*30 to *030 ; then if you are on 003* and set it 2 => 0032 you iterate from 0*32 to *032 ; hope this makes it more clear

Comment: Frankly, I'm not able to grasp it. And I read it like thousand times. Can you please try to expand on the pseudo-code a bit?

Comment: oh i see, there's gone sth wrong with the format; I'll expand it later for you

Comment: Indeed that does it. I ran it for 12 letters and up to about '4' values, and it seems consistent. Thanks a lot. Wow!

Answer (score 1):

A rough sketch in pseudo C#/Java:

Mapping A-L to indexes 0-11

```
const int[] maxvalues = { define max values for each var }
int[] counters = { initialize with 0s }

while (true)
{
  for(i in 11..0)
  {
    counters[i]++;
    if (counters[i] < maxvalues[i])
      break;   // for
    counters[i] = 0;
  }

  if (counters[0] == maxvalues[0])
    break;     // while

  print(counters.ToDisplayString());
}
```

(Just noted that the second sequence does not match the first sequence in OP. If OP is correct, I guess I didn't "get" the sequence)

Comment: if(counters[0] = maxvalues[0]) should be if(counters[0] == maxvalues[0])

Comment: Hi, thanks, I cannot determine by eye whether it does what it should. Give me a moment to try it. :)

Comment: @SmartK8: it cannot match, because there exists no formal way to describe that sequence.

Comment: This gives me equivalent of having for cycle per letter. So if maximal value for C is 1000 it goes 0-1000 first, the increments B by 1, and C goes 0-1000 again. Not good.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of numbers you've described can be enumerated by counting upward from 0 in a base representation of numbers one higher than the amount of "letters" used to create your individual sequences.

One simple way to do this is to use a [radix converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) from base 10 which will act on a variable being incremented in a single loop from 0 to the maximum number of combinations you are looking to achieve.

Here is an implementation:

```
void Main()
{
    for(int i=0; i< 50; i++){
     Console.Write(convert(5,i));
     Console.Write("\n");
    }
}

string convert(int N, int M){
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();

    while (M >= N){
     stack.Push(M %N);
     M = M / N;
    }
    string str = M.ToString();
    while(stack.Count() > 0)
      str = str + stack.Pop().ToString();
    return str;
}
```

Starting output:

0
1
2
3
4
10
11
12
13
14
20
21
22
23
24
30
31
32
33
34
40
41
42
43
44
100
101
102
103
104

Comment: How can I then decode how many pieces (number) of what letter?

Comment: This doesn't produce OP's sequence. Note that her sequence changes **direction** between 12th and 15th element (if observed as a base-n number).

Comment: @Groo, The OP's sequence (which isn't fully explained) seems to be a trivial variation on the sequence I provide.

Comment: I just don't know how to decode for example 13 back to A=1 (1 piece), B=2 (2 pieces), C=1 (1 piece)? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: (A=1, B=2, C=1 was an example)